# How do I create conditional htaccess pass a different variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to figure out this scenario: 
I need to rewrite

```
url.com/a/b/c/1
```

into

```
url.com?page_id=1&listing[make]=a&listing[model]=b&listing[region]=c
```

exceptions

```
url.com/a/all/c/1
```

into

```
url.com?page_id=1&listing[make]=a&listing[model]=&listing[region]=c
```

etc

I have no idea how to creat a negative conditional based on string match within the variable that is being transferred. in this case if the variable is "all"

Comment: Just add the more specific rewriteRule in front of the generic one.

Comment: I have figured it out - I was using QSA at the end - not sure why and it was appending the new url to the old one.